# Scrollable table in CSS3 but without scrollable header

Tags: html, css

I created a scrollable table in html, but I don't want the header to be scrollable.

```
<div style="max-height:80px;width:10%;overflow-y: scroll">
<div style="display:table">
    <div id="table_header" style="display:table-row;background-color:gray"> 
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            Name
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            Age
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row"> 
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            Zarazaz 
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            13 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row"> 
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            Kamuff 
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            123 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            Darandund 
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            145
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            Bazabunzi 
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell"> 
            145
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to put the header outside the table, but the problem in doing so is that the columns may resize depending on the length of the text inside, then the header would end-up being not aligned with the columns below (especially if I need to have more columns). What do you suggest to do?

Comment: I see nothing new in that approach. You just use `<div>` instead of the usual table elements. You could achieve the same with `<table>` and alike ...

Answer (score 0):

You can better use a table for this. I searched the internet for `tbody scrolling` and I got some results that can help you further:

- [Info #1](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/11/10/creating-cross-browser-scrollable-tbody/)
- [Info #2](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html)
- [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu)

Comment: I can't see the JsFiddle example

Comment: @user1883212 jsfiddle is not working at the moment.. So I found an example at codepen.